# When i try "npm install -g @vue/cli" i have an error. Why?

Tags: vue.js, npm

**Hello, when i try this command on my cmd "npm install -g @vue/cl" i have this error:**

> $ npm install -g @vue/cli
> npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
> npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
> npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
> npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
> npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
> npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
> npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
> npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
> npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
> npm ERR! code 1
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\Yanni\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli\node_modules@apollo\protobufjs
> npm ERR! command failed
> npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/postinstall
> npm ERR! 'node' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
> npm ERR! ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Yanni\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-06-29T15_38_02_323Z-debug.log

**How can i fix that ?**

I've already try:

- "npm install vue"
  "npm cache clean --force"
  "npm install -g @vue/cli"
- npm update
- and some more issues

But didn't work.

Comment: Look at the debug log file listed for possible helpful messages.

Answer (score 0):

The response was more simple than i was thinked !

**Use Cmd on admin option and not something else.**